# Replace null with last non-null value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I know the question has been asked several times before, but I am encountering a strange behaviour and hence the question.

Input df

```
   A         B  C
USA 21-07-2018  
USA 22-07-2018  
USA 23-07-2018  1
USA 24-07-2018  1
USA 25-07-2018  1
USA 26-07-2018  1
USA 27-07-2018  1
USA 28-07-2018  
USA 29-07-2018  
USA 30-07-2018  1
USA 31-07-2018  1
USA 01-08-2018  1
USA 02-08-2018  1
USA 03-08-2018  1
USA 04-08-2018  
USA 05-08-2018  
USA 06-08-2018  1
USA 07-08-2018  1
USA 08-08-2018  1
USA 09-08-2018  1
USA 10-08-2018  1
USA 11-08-2018  
USA 12-08-2018  
USA 13-08-2018  1
USA 14-08-2018  1
USA 15-08-2018  1
USA 16-08-2018  1
USA 17-08-2018  1
USA 18-08-2018  
USA 19-08-2018
```

I tried out the below two methods

1st Method

```
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

2nd Method

```
 df['C'] = df['C'].ffill()
```

Both of them resulted in the same dataframe(Output_df)

```
  A          B  C
USA 21-07-2017  1
USA 22-07-2017  3010.77
USA 23-07-2017  3010.77
USA 24-07-2017  1
USA 25-07-2017  1
USA 26-07-2017  1
USA 27-07-2017  1
USA 28-07-2017  1
USA 29-07-2017  2995.23
USA 30-07-2017  2995.23
USA 31-07-2017  1
USA 01-08-2017  1
USA 02-08-2017  1
USA 03-08-2017  1
USA 04-08-2017  1
USA 05-08-2017  2974.39
USA 06-08-2017  2974.39
USA 07-08-2017  1
USA 08-08-2017  1
USA 09-08-2017  1
USA 10-08-2017  1
USA 11-08-2017  1
```

Why am I getting value like 3010.77, 2974.39 etc. Is this being averaged out somewhere (input df is quite large >25k rows) ?

What I expected it to be(Expected_df)

```
  A          B  C
USA 21-07-2018  1
USA 22-07-2018  1
USA 23-07-2018  1
USA 24-07-2018  1
USA 25-07-2018  1
USA 26-07-2018  1
USA 27-07-2018  1
USA 28-07-2018  1
USA 29-07-2018  1
USA 30-07-2018  1
USA 31-07-2018  1
USA 01-08-2018  1
USA 02-08-2018  1
USA 03-08-2018  1
USA 04-08-2018  1
USA 05-08-2018  1
USA 06-08-2018  1
USA 07-08-2018  1
USA 08-08-2018  1
USA 09-08-2018  1
USA 10-08-2018  1
USA 11-08-2018  1
USA 12-08-2018  1
USA 13-08-2018  1
USA 14-08-2018  1
USA 15-08-2018  1
USA 16-08-2018  1
USA 17-08-2018  1
USA 18-08-2018  1
USA 19-08-2018  1
```

**Just to give another example of my expected output**

Input df

```
  A          B         C
AUS 21-07-2017  1.262584
AUS 22-07-2017  
AUS 23-07-2017  
AUS 24-07-2017  1.258671
AUS 25-07-2017  1.256456
AUS 26-07-2017  1.263913
AUS 27-07-2017  1.249957
AUS 28-07-2017  1.256032
AUS 29-07-2017  
AUS 30-07-2017  
AUS 31-07-2017  1.254626
AUS 01-08-2017  1.254064
AUS 02-08-2017  1.255136
AUS 03-08-2017  1.259949
AUS 04-08-2017  1.254466
AUS 05-08-2017  
AUS 06-08-2017  
AUS 07-08-2017  1.263796
AUS 08-08-2017  1.259692
AUS 09-08-2017  1.268349
AUS 10-08-2017  1.269008
AUS 11-08-2017  1.271738
```

(Expected)Output df

```
  A          B         C
AUS 21-07-2017  1.262584
AUS 22-07-2017  1.262584
AUS 23-07-2017  1.262584
AUS 24-07-2017  1.258671
AUS 25-07-2017  1.256456
AUS 26-07-2017  1.263913
AUS 27-07-2017  1.249957
AUS 28-07-2017  1.256032
AUS 29-07-2017  1.256032
AUS 30-07-2017  1.256032
AUS 31-07-2017  1.254626
AUS 01-08-2017  1.254064
AUS 02-08-2017  1.255136
AUS 03-08-2017  1.259949
AUS 04-08-2017  1.254466
AUS 05-08-2017  1.254466
AUS 06-08-2017  1.254466
AUS 07-08-2017  1.263796
AUS 08-08-2017  1.259692
AUS 09-08-2017  1.268349
AUS 10-08-2017  1.269008
AUS 11-08-2017  1.271738
```

Comment: What is the result of `df["C"].dtype`?

Comment: @Chris It returns object.

Comment: @RoshanShah22 For expected behaviour, you might want to convert `whitespace` into `np.nan` and then run `ffill()`.

Comment: @jezrael I just let OP know that for expected behaviour of `ffill()`, he should remove whitespaces first and then use `ffill`. I didn't comment about strange numbers.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Not understand, OP ask why got strange numbers, your answer replace whitespaces to NaNs, not understand it.

Comment: @jezrael There are 2 parts to this question. First, that he is receiving strange numbers, 2nd, he wants `ffill()` to work as expected. I am talking about the 2nd part as this will solve his issue.  Hope its clear now.

Comment: 2nd part is where ask? Cannot find in question.

Comment: @jezrael Check his expected output. That means he wants `ffill`.

Comment: yes, I cannot find where ask why ffill cannot replace values (so reason whitespace)

Comment: You have too much confusion. Also, OP is not responding for a long time. You can simply close the question with `Need more details or clarity`.

Comment: @jezrael  I did not explicitly mention it, but I wanted the answer to the 2nd part too that Mayank Porwal has answered. Sorry for the confusion guys, but I'd really like to know the reason behind this strange behavior too

Comment: @RoshanShah22 Please confirm if you have `blanks` or `whitespaces` in your data. Or are those completely different invisible characters?

Comment: I hope no reason for close, I think in comments it shoul dbe explained. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `whitespaces` in your column. You need to replace those with `numpy.nan`.

If you are unsure about how many blanks are there, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
df['C'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Then use `ffill()` for expected behaviour.

```
df['C'] = df['C'].ffill()
```

Comment: I tried this, now the entire 'C' column is null, anything I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: So you are saying that there are no blanks in your column `C`?

Comment: The dataframe posted above is a time-series data and you can kind of make out that on Saturdays and Sundays, no data is recorded and hence you have NaN there, as visible on my IDE

Comment: I don't think these are `Nan`. You can confirm by running `df[df['C'].isna()]`. Please tell me what is the output of this?

Comment: This just returns the dataframe with entire column 'C' with NaN

Comment: No, please do this on your original dataframe. Not after applying the commands from my answer. I want to check if there are any actual `NaN` originally in your df or not?

Comment: No, that is what I did `print(df[df['C'].isna()])` before your answer. I did this to my orignal dataframe. Don't know why this happened, should have returned either true or False

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225145/discussion-between-roshanshah22-and-mayank-porwal).